# Check if a TextView is completely visible

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `ListView` with an adapter attached. The data behind it is a couple of articles. The articles have a title and a subtitle, the length of both varies. 
Sometimes the text of either one is so long that the `TextView` doesn't fit the View created by the adapter which has a fixed height.
Is there a possibility to find out if both `TextViews` are completely visible within the View? 
I know I would have to wait for the layout to be drawn, would do it with `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can only completely fit two lines per title and subtitle. If I were you, I'd measure the length of the text with the paint that's used to draw it and see if it's less than (width of line) * (number of lines).

For example, consider the following:

```
boolean doesTitleFitBounds = titleTextView.getPaint().measureText(titleText) < (TITLE_LINE_WIDTH * TITLE_NUM_ROWS);
```

where TITLE_LINE_WIDTH is the available width for your text in pixels (accounting for paddings/margins etc) and TITLE_NUM_ROWS is the number of rows you have per title.
Similarly, you can do a check for the subtitle to see if it fits its own bounds.